# A common word for holiday, unplanned absence and overtime or Time in lieu

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any common word for holiday/unplanned absence/overtime/Time in lieu/Lateness ?

Thanks for your input.

I want to create a software which will let people manage all things above together at a single place.

Comment: Please see the [tag info for single-word-requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info), and edit examples of how you intend to use the word into your question.

Comment: Some of these examples are completely different things for instance holidays, vacations, unplanned absence (like being sick) could all be considered a [leave of absence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leave_of_absence) or 'leave' for short. However lateness and time in the lieu are totally different.

Comment: I don't get it. In what way is *overtime* related to *absence*? Context please.

Comment: Are you talking about exceptions to the standard "paid salary for work done"?

Comment: What is the unifying theme that makes you want to tie these together?

Comment: Unpunctual: Since nothing is happening at the scheduled time.

Comment: The only phrase I can think of that includes both time off and overtime is _time recording_.

Answer (score 1):

The only word which means not being the office when you would normally be expected to be is ***absence.***

But that doesn't cover overtime, which is being present when you shouldn't be.

Consequently what you are handling are instances where the general rule or expectation is not followed. These are generally termed ***exceptions*** and your application is for *exception reporting.* "Attendance Exception Report" probably has a sufficiently jargony ring to it.

> **Exception**
> A person or thing that is excluded from a general statement or does not follow a rule
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/exception)